# Array size as a random variable in graphical models

Tags: joint-distribution, graphical-model, dependent-variable

Assume that I want to model a mixture of sentences. There are two different sources generating sentences with specific sentence length and word distribution. I had came up with the following graphical model which is for sure incomplete ($N$ is the dictionary size):

[image: The Graphical Model]

I know that it is not correct to assume the independence of the length and the "array" of words while it is incorrect, as well, to say existence of $Word_i$ in a sentence is dependent to its length.

So there are two questions:

- How should we graphically represent such dependencies?
- (More important than the previous one) How can we calculate the joint distribution $P(S, L,\{W_i\}^N_{i=1})$?